# Error Inserting Image into Database c#

Tags: c#, mysql

**ERROR [HY000] [MySQL][ODBC5.3(a) 
Driver][mysqlId-5.7.11] Column 'Images'
cannot be null.** (This is my Problem)

This is my inserting button code

```
OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection("dsn=dsn_pos");
        MessageBox.Show(this.imagePath.Text);
        FileStream filestreme = new FileStream(imagePath.Text,System.IO.FileMode.Open,System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
        byte[] image = new byte[filestreme.Length];
        filestreme.Read(image, 0, Convert.ToInt32(filestreme.Length));
        filestreme.Close();




        connection.Open();
        string query = "INSERT INTO item_inventory (Images) VALUES (?)";
        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(query, connection);
        OdbcParameter prm = new OdbcParameter("@IMG",OdbcType.Binary,image.Length,ParameterDirection.Input,false,0,0,null,DataRowVersion.Current,image);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(prm);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
```

This one is my loading button code

```
 OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        dialog.Filter = "png files(*.png)|*.png|jpg files(*.jpg)|*.jpg|All files(*.*)|*.*";
        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string picPath = dialog.FileName.ToString();
            imagePath.Text = picPath;
            pictureBox2.ImageLocation = picPath;
        }
```

Comment: what is the Images column type?

Comment: images type is blob.

Comment: and why aren't you using the MySql driver? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/

Comment: our project use ODBC MYsql

Comment: thanks @shawkyz1 I solved already ..

Comment: don't forget to edit the answer and write down the solution

Answer (score 0):

The mysql driver works otherwise, it doesn't support named parameters, only orderd. You need to change your @IMG in query to ?.
Afret that you query should be looks like:

```
INSERT INTO item_inventory (Images) VALUES (?)
```

Comment: yeah mysql driver is working.. let me try your suggestion.

Comment: thanks. ? sign is the problem ~_~ why is I need to use ? can i have your explanation for that

Comment: Try to read that one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338139/can-odbc-parameter-place-holders-be-named

Comment: yah for SQL @ and for odbc ?

Comment: in fact I'm not strong in terminology, but I know this problem in practice. therefore I apologize that I can not give you an answer with an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

this is the answer string query = "INSERT INTO item_inventory (Images) VALUES (?)";