# Pass ssrs parameter to bigquery SP

Tags: stored-procedures, reporting-services, google-bigquery, parameters, simba

I can call from SSRS BiqQuery SP when I put parameter manually (, but when I try to give report parameter to SP I got this error message.

> "Error [42000] [Simba]Bigquery Invalid query: Syntax error:
> Expected end of input but got identifier "MyDataset" at [1:1]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use ODBC positional parameters with BigQuery.Declare your SSRS parameters on BQ and after that try again.
Pay attention to the order.

Example:

DECLARE parameter1 = ?;
DECLARE parameter2 = ?;

SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE clause1=parameter1 AND clause2=parameter2;

Here's a link;
[Can ODBC parameter place holders be named?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338139/can-odbc-parameter-place-holders-be-named)